# How to mock msal framework for python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, azure-ad-msal

Sample code is present here : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp

I would like to learn how to mock below code to create unit tests for login and authorization route.
get request to '/login' route should redirect it to '/authorized' route , yet I am failing to do so.
Would appreciate any help on this!

```
import uuid
import msal
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, session, jsonify, url_for
from app.scripts import _load_cache,_save_cache,_build_msal_app,_get_token_from_cache
from app import config
from app import flask_app
from app import session_app


@flask_app.route("/")
@flask_app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if "user" in session:
        return redirect(url_for("application_view"))
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    session["flow"] = _build_auth_code_flow(scopes=config.SCOPE)
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=session["flow"]["auth_uri"], version=msal.__version__)

@flask_app.route(config.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    feedback = {"message:":""}

    try: #The authorization code returned from Authorization Server.
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
            session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
        #print(result)
        if "error" in result:
            feedback["message"] = result["error_description"]
            return render_template('login.html', feedback=feedback)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        
        _save_cache(cache)
    except ValueError:  # Usually caused by CSRF
        pass  # Simply ignore them
    return redirect(url_for("application_view")) #application route
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow all of the instructions in the documentation you provided above if you wish to simulate the msal framework. In Python, you can use pytest or the unittest library for unit testing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274594/how-do-i-send-credentials-so-i-can-unit-test-msal-for-python) is a guide that shares the steps to unit test MSAL for Python.